# Way to switch F keys to 'application' keys and back on mac via terminal? (10.6)

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, applescript

Is there a command I can issue via terminal to switch my F1-12 keys to being application keys (media, screen brightness ...) and back? i.e. replicate toggling `System Preferences => Keyboard => Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys`. My mac is pretty much used for browsing and music but it is nice not to have to fn to the F keys when occasionally doing some Chrome debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only know how to do this via UI scripting. Open up *AppleScript Editor*, and paste the following:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of window "Keyboard"
    end tell
    tell application "System Preferences" to quit
end tell
```

Like this:

[image]

Save it under any name you like. From a Terminal, you can then run:

```
osascript toggle-f.scpt
```

Comment: Here's a more extensive version: http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=15246334&postcount=8